# Using to javascript to add an address bar to the window

Tags: javascript, html, popupwindow

Ok, so I know how to use JS to pop open a new window, control the size of the window that's opened, and also display it without an address bar or scroll controls on the side.

But let's say the user is on my site (in what we'll call window A), they click on a link and now they have this small window (we'll call this window B) open up with no controls or address bar.

Now I want them to click a button that will do one of the 2 following things:

1. It could close window B, and on window A go to a new URL specified by the button clicked on window B.
2. It could resize window B (I know how to resize with a javascript action) and add back in the address bar and ability to scroll (this, I do not know how to do).

Do people follow what I'm attempting to accomplish here? If you need a better explanation, please ask, and I'll help clarify.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind `window.close()` to the button event, and also use `window.opener.location` to change the location of the window A:

```
$('#button2').on('click', function () {
    window.opener.location = 'http://yoursite.com/';
    window.close();
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eCTfF/1/
Edit: for it to work, you have to go to http://jsfiddle.net/eCTfF/1/show - outside the JSFiddle iframe.

As for number 2, I'd need some clarification on what you mean.

Comment: Wow! That's exactly what I was looking for!  Thank you! No need to attempt option 2 since you gave me a great way to make option 1 work.  I haven't implemented it yet, but that's what I'm about to start working on.  Thank you!

Comment: It works great! I just put it in my site and it does exactly what I wanted it to do! Thank you so much!